# Get all links on the same domain using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, dom, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I'm writing code to crawl links on a given web page.  I'm trying out [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) to read the html contents (using [www.google.co.uk](http://www.google.co.uk) in my example). The code I'm using is as follows:

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var links = GetLinks(new Uri("https://www.google.co.uk"));
        foreach (var link in links)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(link);
        }
    }

    private static List<string> GetLinks(Uri uri)
    {
        var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(uri);
        return doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
            .Select(a => a.GetAttributeValue("href", null))
            .Distinct()
            .Where(u => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(u)).ToList();
    }
}
```

I'm stripping out nulls and duplicate links.  This gives the following result:

```
 - https://www.google.co.uk/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi
 - https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?hl=en&tab=wl
 - https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8
 - https://www.youtube.com/?gl=GB&tab=w1 
 - https://news.google.com/?tab=wn
 - https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm 
 - https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo
 - https://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh
 - http://www.google.co.uk/history/optout?hl=en 
 - /preferences?hl=en
 - https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.co.uk/&ec=GAZAAQ
 - /advanced_search?hl=en-GB&amp;authuser=0 
 - /intl/en/ads/ 
 - /services/
 - /intl/en/about.html
 - https://www.google.co.uk/setprefdomain?prefdom=US&amp;sig=K_eDMDym3RsPb7-MzvJkS4b2Eg4ns%3D
 - /intl/en/policies/privacy/ 
 - /intl/en/policies/terms/
```

I'd like to narrow down the links even further to select links that only match the same subdomain "www.google.co.uk", including relative URL's.  The resulting list would be narrowed down to this:

```
 - https://www.google.co.uk/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi
 - https://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh
 - http://www.google.co.uk/history/optout?hl=en 
 - /preferences?hl=en
 - /advanced_search?hl=en-GB&amp;authuser=0 
 - /intl/en/ads/ 
 - /services/
 - /intl/en/about.html
 - https://www.google.co.uk/setprefdomain?prefdom=US&amp;sig=K_eDMDym3RsPb7-MzvJkS4b2Eg4ns%3D
 - /intl/en/policies/privacy/ 
 - /intl/en/policies/terms/
```

I'm looking to modify the code above in the most efficient way to achieve this but not sure of the best way to approach it with HtmlAgilityPack.  I've arrived at this solution:

```cs
private static List<string> GetLinks(Uri uri)
{
    var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(uri);
    return doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
        .Select(a => 
        { 
            var val = a.GetAttributeValue("href", null);

            if (val.StartsWith("/"))
                val = $"{uri.Scheme}://{uri.Host}{val}";

            return val;
        })
        .Distinct()
        .Where(u =>
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(u) 
                   && u.Contains(uri.Host); // using contains here is a problem
        }).ToList();
}
```

I'm very conscious of the amount of string manipulation involved here in changing relative urls to fully qualified and also matching on "Contains", which could leave incorrect results.  Does anyone have a less wasteful (string comparison and manipulation) solution to this?

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thats a fair point Brian! Although the `Contains(uri.Host)` does yield the wrong result in the case of this link `https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.co.uk/&ec=GAZAAQ` as it sees the matching domain name in the query string param.  (I can't use `StartsWith` either as I don't want to discriminate between http and https links when matching domain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your HTML is huge and has a multitude of links, I wouldn't be that worried about optimizing for performance here.

It sounds like the main problem is just finding a replacement for `Contains` in the `Where` clause.  I would use a `Regex` for that.  You can build the match pattern once, at the beginning of your method, and then use `IsMatch` inside the `Where`, like so:

```
private static List<string> GetLinks(Uri uri)
{
    var regex = new Regex("^http(s)?://" + uri.Host, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(uri);

    return doc.DocumentNode
        .Descendants("a")
        .Select(a =>
        {
            var val = a.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
            return val.StartsWith("/") ? uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + val : val;
        })
        .Distinct()
        .Where(u => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(u) && regex.IsMatch(u))
        .ToList();
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BVdv1Y

Comment: Thanks Brian!!  This works for most cases but noticed it not working on this test site:
`https://monzo.com/i/current-account/`  It didnt pickup the querystring from this element:

`<a href="https://www.monzo.com/-deeplinks/paid?google_client_id=1091015212.1617383050" class="Button-module__primary___1GlDI Button-module__button___UaHzb PaidButton-module__paidButtonStyles___2Smin PaidButton-module__font-caption-bold___1OBtg PaidButton-module__font-caption-size___1ysSL" data-testid="Button">Get Monzo Premium</a>` any ideas why it would miss that?

Comment: If the host name in your URI is `monzo.com` then it won't pick up `www.monzo.com` because that's not the same host.  You could change the regex to allow for an optional `www.` prefix on the host name:  `^http(s)?://(www\.)?`

Comment: Brilliant Brian! Thanks a million for your help, very much appreciated!

Comment: No problem; glad I could help!